# Issues playing video files using MVC FileStream

Tags: asp.net-mvc, video-streaming, html5-video, mediaelement.js

I'm trying to use the following code to retrieve video files to play to a user:

```
public class VideoController : Controller
{
    public VideoResult GetMP4Video(string videoID)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string clipLocation = string.Format("{0}\\Completed\\{1}.mp4", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VideoLocation"].ToString(), videoID);

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(clipLocation, FileMode.Open))
            {
                FileStreamResult fsResult = new FileStreamResult(stream, "video/mp4");
                VideoResult result = new VideoResult(ReadFully(fsResult.FileStream), "video/mp4");

                return result;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

For displaying to the client I'm using Media Element:

```
<!-- Video Player Here -->
<video width="640" height="360" poster="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Videos/{0}_2.jpg", Model.VideoID))" controls="controls" preload="none">
<!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
<source type="video/mp4" src="@Url.Action("GetMP4Video", "Video", new { videoID = Model.VideoID })" />
<!-- Flash fallback for non-HTML5 browsers without JavaScript -->
    <object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ME/flashmediaelement.swf")">
        <param name="movie" value="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ME/flashmediaelement.swf")" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=@Url.Action("GetMP4Video", "Video", new { videoID = Model.VideoID })" />
        <!-- Image as a last resort -->
        <img src="myvideo.jpg" width="320" height="240" title="No video playback capabilities" />
    </object>
</video>
```

The problem is though that the file doesn't seem to play or at least not consistently. Also seeking in the video doesn not appear to work properly either. I guess my question is is this a acceptable way to serve a video to a user? If so what have I got wrong? I think its important that I'm very new to video and I'm very much learning as I go. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ahh whata good question man! I am doing the same for a project of my own.. we cannot specify file direct so how can we server mp4 streams?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. Adapted from [here](http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/easy-handling-of-http-range-requests-in-asp-net/):

```
 internal static void StreamVideo(string fullpath, HttpContextBase context)
    {
        long size, start, end, length, fp = 0;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fullpath))
        {

            size = reader.BaseStream.Length;
            start = 0;
            end = size - 1;
            length = size;
            // Now that we've gotten so far without errors we send the accept range header
            /* At the moment we only support single ranges.
             * Multiple ranges requires some more work to ensure it works correctly
             * and comply with the spesifications: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.2
             *
             * Multirange support annouces itself with:
             * header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
             *
             * Multirange content must be sent with multipart/byteranges mediatype,
             * (mediatype = mimetype)
             * as well as a boundry header to indicate the various chunks of data.
             */
            context.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "0-" + size);
            // header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
            // multipart/byteranges
            // http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.2

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_RANGE"]))
            {
                long anotherStart = start;
                long anotherEnd = end;
                string[] arr_split = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_RANGE"].Split(new char[] { Convert.ToChar("=") });
                string range = arr_split[1];

                // Make sure the client hasn't sent us a multibyte range
                if (range.IndexOf(",") > -1)
                {
                    // (?) Shoud this be issued here, or should the first
                    // range be used? Or should the header be ignored and
                    // we output the whole content?
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
                    throw new HttpException(416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable");

                }

                // If the range starts with an '-' we start from the beginning
                // If not, we forward the file pointer
                // And make sure to get the end byte if spesified
                if (range.StartsWith("-"))
                {
                    // The n-number of the last bytes is requested
                    anotherStart = size - Convert.ToInt64(range.Substring(1));
                }
                else
                {
                    arr_split = range.Split(new char[] { Convert.ToChar("-") });
                    anotherStart = Convert.ToInt64(arr_split[0]);
                    long temp = 0;
                    anotherEnd = (arr_split.Length > 1 && Int64.TryParse(arr_split[1].ToString(), out temp)) ? Convert.ToInt64(arr_split[1]) : size;
                }
                /* Check the range and make sure it's treated according to the specs.
                 * http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
                 */
                // End bytes can not be larger than $end.
                anotherEnd = (anotherEnd > end) ? end : anotherEnd;
                // Validate the requested range and return an error if it's not correct.
                if (anotherStart > anotherEnd || anotherStart > size - 1 || anotherEnd >= size)
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fullpath);
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
                    throw new HttpException(416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable");
                }
                start = anotherStart;
                end = anotherEnd;

                length = end - start + 1; // Calculate new content length
                fp = reader.BaseStream.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                context.Response.StatusCode = 206;
            }
        }
        // Notify the client the byte range we'll be outputting
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", length.ToString());
        // Start buffered download
        context.Response.WriteFile(fullpath, fp, length);
        context.Response.End();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are trying to put a mp4 file served by a webserver into a player which is embedded in your HTML file, and it would not play properly (unless the file is comparitively very small or you are having an extremely fast internet connection, so that the file gets downloaded to the browser's temp folder fast).

To properly stream video files, please follow any of the steps below.

1. use Windows media Server/ Flash media Server. Push your webcam to the server by Windows Media Encoder or flash media encoder, and use the server live link to link with your website via any suitable player (like jwplayer).
2. Use Windows Media Encoder to stream your webcam to anyone without a server involved. when your encoder starts, you will get a URL to view your stream, which you can use to publish in your site.
3. use third party streaming services, where they give you a publishing point to publish your webcam stream, and use the link provided by them to show it on your website. (check with brighcove or Mogulus by LiveStream

Hope this helps.